# The category of complexes over a dg-algebra is Grothendieck (it has a generator)

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a dg-algebra over some commutative ring $k$. We have an abelian category $\mathrm{C}(A)$ of (right) $A$-dg-modules. I've read in a few sources that $\mathrm{C}(A)$ is a Grothendieck abelian category. Indeed, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{C}(A)= Z^0(\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathrm{dg}}(A^\mathrm{op}, \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{dg}}(k)),
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{dg}}(k)$ is the dg-category of $k$-dg-modules, and $\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathrm{dg}}(,)$ denotes the dg-category of dg-functors, and $Z^0(\mathbf A)$ is the underlying category of any dg-category $\mathbf{A}$ (take $0$-cocycles). Hence, it is quite easy to check that filtered colimits are exact in $\mathrm{C}(A)$.

Now, I wonder: how do I check that $\mathrm{C}(A)$ has a generator? Perhaps should I again use the description of $\mathrm{C}(A)$ as a category of (dg)-functors and the fact that $\mathrm{C}(k)$ has a generator? Is there a reference for this result?

Comment: Isn't $C(A)$ just generated by the direct sum of the suspensions of $A$?

Comment: @KevinCarlson could you give me a reference or an idea of proof?

Comment: It's an elaboration of the argument for ordinary rings. $A$-module maps from $A[i]$ to $B$ are maps from $A$ to $B[-i]$, which are uniquely determined by the image of $1$ so correspond to elements of the codomain, and a nonzero map out of $B$ must be nonzero on some element.

Comment: But in a dg algebra d(1)=0, so you are sure to cover only elements b in B such that d(b)=0. Isn't it?

Comment: @MarcoFarinati Ah, interesting!

Answer (score 4):

As Marco Farinati pointed out, $A$ is *not* the free dg-$A$-module on one degree-$0$ generator, since $A$ represents in fact the functor of degree-$0$ cycles, not of degree-$0$ elements. However, if we can construct $A$-modules $R_i$ which are free on a generator in degree $i$, so that $C(A)(R_i, S)=S_i$, rather than the cycles in $S_i$, then $\oplus R_i$ will generate $C(A)$. And it is not hard to show such $R_i$ must exist. The functors $S\mapsto S_i$ into sets preserve limits and satisfy the solution set condition since a map $X\to S_i$ of sets must factor through a submodule of $S$ of bounded cardinality, say no bigger than the product $|A||X|\aleph_0$. So the general adjoint functor theorem produces our modules $R_i$. I don't have an general explicit description for $R_i$ worked out, but if $A=k$ it's simply $...\to 0\to k \to k \to 0\to...$, where $k$ appears in degrees $i$ and $i+1$.

Comment: I think you're working too hard. Let the complex $R_i$ be $A[i] \oplus A[i-1]$, with differential $\begin{pmatrix}d_A & 0\\1 & d_A\end{pmatrix}.$ Then if $M$ is a dg-module with $x \in M_i$ an element, the map $R_i \to M$ given by sending $1 \in A[i]$ to $x$ and $1 \in A[i-1]$ to $dx$ is a chain map of dg-modules (maybe up to some signs I haven't checked).

Comment: The differential should have a factor of $(-1)^{|a|}$ (the sign depending on the degree of the element $a$ it acts on) instead of $1$. Otherwise, this is your desired complex. Or, I guess, leave the differential what it is and just change the map corresponding to $x \in M$.

Comment: In other words, take $A$, the mapping cone $Cone(id_A)$, and all its suspensions, and you get a ser of generators

Comment: Actually I thought this works when you are over a field, but after Kevin Carson's answer seems to work in general

Comment: @MikeMiller Actually, you worked harder than me!